# One component of xml layout don't show

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `xml` layout and I have some problem.

**Problem One:**

This is user for chat application.I have a `LinearLayout` that contains an `EditText`.android studio preview shows this `LinearLayout` but when run application on my device,isn't shown.

**Problem Two:**

I want to add padding-right to `EditText` to get away from send icon.I add padding but don't work.

**Problem Three:**

How to access my send icon in the activity to set `OnClickListener` for it.

**Problem Four:** Text of `EditText` appears bold while I don't give bold style to it.
This is my `xml` file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_upwards_arrow"
            android:hint="نوشتن پیام"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: My output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_chatbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

         <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/sendBtn"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:hint="نوشتن پیام"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendBtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/sendBtn">
    </EditText>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext_chatbox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/layout_chatbox">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Sarina, I have edited the code. Please check if it can solve your problem now.

Answer (score 2):

> Problem One:

Use **`RelativeLayout`** as your root layout and make **`layout_chatbox`** `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

> Problem Two:

Use **`ImageView`** instead of `android:drawableRight` like in my below code

> Problem Three:

Now your can easily use `OnClickListener` for `imageview`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_chatbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivsend"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="enter Text Here"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivsend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> android:background="@drawable/test"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I want to my icon be inside `EditText` but in your solution it to be placed out of `EditText`.

Comment: Yes,but not complete.Problem four didn't solve and When the code that is mentioned in `Handling click events on a drawable within an EditText` post is placed in my program,that section is yellow and has warning.Also I don't know how make dark color when pressed on my icon inside an EditText.

Comment: @sarina  why don't to use imageview for icon wait i will update my answer

Comment: @sarina  check updated answer it gives same output as when u set `android:drawableRight`

Comment: I want to the icon placed within the EditText but in your code it placed besides the EditText.

Comment: @sarina can u share image as output so i can modifies my answer

Comment: how to share it? Here?

Comment: @sarina you can add image in your question

Comment: The image format is `SVG` and Stack overflow doesn't allow me to put here. I download my icon from flaticon.com . However, no matter what image you place

Comment: @sarina i don;t need the image  of your icon i need the image of your expected output

Comment: sorry. I put the output image.

Comment: please pick up duplicate marker of newest  my question

Comment: @sarina sorry i can't its duplicate question

Comment: I edit my question and my problem didn't solve by those answer. because my problem is different!!!!!]